# How to change the font color for parameter values or attribute values in SQL Server?

Tags: fonts, sql-server-2012, ssms

I use SQL Server at work and I wanted to have a dark theme, so I edited the font colors for my text editor, and it now looks like below (Please refer the link):

I was able to change the font color for everything else, but I was not able to change the font color for the parameter values. It is currently black, which makes it hard to read on the dark background.

```
/*sample snippet*/
DECLARE @subject NVARCHAR(255) ,
        @body NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @query NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
        @ProgressToStaging BIT = 0,
        @CurrentRow INT = 1;
```

The values '0' and '1' in the above snippet are formatted as black. Can I get help on where to change the font color for this?

P.S.: I have tried different options in tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts & Colors

Comment: A few years ago I used Obsydian: http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2012/06/26/beautify-your-management-studio-2012/ I guess you could localize vssettings file and change color from there.

Comment: Thanks for the response Lukasz. But, since I do it on my office work station, I do not have the admin privileges to edit the vss files.

Comment: You could still import them `Tools –> Import and Export Settings`

Comment: Got it! Thanks.